# #heroku ERROR: column c.relhasoids does not exist LINE 1: ...riggers, c.relrowsecurity, c.relforcerowsecurity, c.relhasoi

Tags: postgresql, heroku

[image: screenshot]

Postgres 12.3 is running on Heroku VM. Can create new tables, select and insert data, but /d not working

Comment: Your `psql` version does not match your server version

Comment: thanks. I scrolled up and saw this in the console